# Unable to locate element href </a>

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, href

Please find the attached image i want to fetch the Admins and moderators name and href link .

i have tried below :

```
grp="https://m.facebook.com/groups/162265541050378?view=members&ref=m_notif&notif_t=group_r2j_approved"
driver.get(grp)
root1=driver.find_element_by_id("//*[@id='rootcontainer']")
if root1>0:
    admin=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_4kk6 _5b6s']")
    ilink = admin.get_attribute('href')
    ilink2=admin.get_attribute('<a>')
    print(ilink)
```

error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="//*[@id='rootcontainer']"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **Admins and moderators name** you can do this :

```
for names in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, 'member_')]/div[2]/descendant::h3[1]")
    print(names.text)
```

for **href** :

```
for hrefs in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, 'member_')]/div[4]/descendant::a")
     print(hrefs.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: I have updated the code, Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: for href not able to get the href link getting only text name . and getting printed two times

Comment: My bad ! I have updated the code. use this `print(hrefs.get_attribute('href'))`

Comment: working thanks . can please advise how should print only  Admins and moderators names in name.text as it is printing other members name also refer screenshot.

Comment: Admins and moderators names is known to you ? I mean in advance do you know how many are there

Comment: not actually but i have to deal with Admins and moderators only . others are not required so i was asking how should i neglect them. and also in href it is printing two time in loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233782/discussion-between-pkk-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: @pkk : I have updated the code in the discussion, try it out and let me know

Answer (score 1):

First of all `//*[@id='rootcontainer']` is XPath, not ID. So you can use it like this

```
root1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rootcontainer']")
```

or this:

```
root1=driver.find_element_by_id("rootcontainer")
```

Also this `ilink2=admin.get_attribute('<a>')` is not correct. Will not work.